# Always quote csv values

Tags: csv, go

I want to quote all fields in a CSV document. Is there a way to modify golang's [csv](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) module without having to copy all the code? In another language, I'd simply inherit from csv.Writer and override [`fieldNeedsQuotes`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/writer.go#L120), but that is not possible in Go, or is it?

Comment: At least in Java and Python, overriden methods will be called from parent classes. Can you produce a program that shows otherwise? [See this demo](http://ideone.com/e4gIZU) and the output.

Comment: Almost: E.g. there is no inheritance lots of other languages. Just copy the code and replace fieldNeedsQuotes with true. Dead simple, no inheritance needed.

Comment: You can't "overrride" methods in Go, and you can't add methods to structs outside the package they're defined in. But, if I may ask, why do you want to quote each value in a CSV file? That's not necessary and can make it much larger, which I bet is why Go doesn't support doing it in the encoding/csv package.

Comment: @Matt Ok, so the best course of action would be to copy the module? If so, this could be an answer. I'm perfectly aware that quotes are unnecessary, but the proprietary software I'm feeding the output of my program to requires them.

Comment: @phihag I can't think of a better way than copying the package and using your own. Although, you may consider extending the encoding/csv package to support an option like `QuoteAllValues` and then submit the idea to the gophers on Google Groups/Google Code, explaining your situation, and see if they'd pull it in.

Answer (score 2):

I see, it's an old question. But I recently faced the same problem, and created a small library `altcsv`, by extending the Golang's `encoding/csv`.

If someone else is wondering about the same, you can use the below library:
https://github.com/tushar2708/altcsv

It's backward compatible with existing CSV library. I plan to add more python-like CSV interface to the same in future.

**Reading from a CSV file:**

```
fileRdr, _ = os.Open("/tmp/custom_csv_file.txt")
csvRdr := altcsv.NewReader(fileRdr)
content := csvReader.ReadAll()
```

**Writing to a CSV file:**

```
headers = []string{"hero_name", "alter_ego", "identity"}
fileWtr, _ := os.Create("/tmp/all_quotes_csv_file.txt")
csvWtr := altcsv.NewWriter(csvH)
csvWtr.AllQuotes = true   // surround each field with '"'
csvWtr.Write(headers)
csvWtr.Write([]string{"Spider-Man", "Peter Parker", "Secret Identity"})
csvWtr.Write([]string{"Captain America", "Steven Rogers", "Public Identity"})
csvWtr.Write([]string{"Thor", "Thor Odinson", "No dual Identity"})
csvWtr.Flush()
fileWtr.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt and Volker already said that you can copy the module and modify it.

You can use a Writer wrapper as well, but I think it's a bit more complex.
See my attempt as a proof of concept (not to be used*).

```
type quoteWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}

func (w quoteWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    q := make([]byte, 0)
    quoted := true
    quoted = (p[0] == '"')
    if !quoted {
        //begin field quote
        q = append(q, '"')
    }

    for i, v := range p {
        //We check the "quotation" status for new field or line
        //This is a simplification
        if v == ',' || v == '\n' {
            if !quoted { //end field quote
                q = append(q, '"')
            }
            //copy current byte
            q = append(q, v)

            //is next byte quote?
            if len(p) > i+1 {
                quoted = (p[i+1] == '"')
            }
            if !quoted { //begin field quote
                q = append(q, '"')
            }
        } else {
            q = append(q, v)
        }
    }

    return w.w.Write(q)
}
```

See below the example coming from the csv#Writer test (http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/writer_test.go) with the proof of concept applied:

http://play.golang.org/p/wovYUkt6Vq

**not to be used*** Please, notice that I haven't checked all cases, for instance, if a comma is within a quoted text or not, so you would need to check and adapt it.
I also recommend to copy and modify the csv package.